# CMake/Ninja attempting to compile deleted `.cpp` file

Tags: c++, cmake, ninja

I've found that when I delete `cpp` files from my project using `cmake` and `ninja`, I can't easily compile it without first completely deleting my build directory and starting from scratch. CMake and/or Ninja apparently squirrels away a number of references to all the `cpp` files that it compiles, even deleting the CMake cache before re-running CMake doesn't remove all the references.

Is this a known issue? Is there a solution? I've occasionally just run `rm $(grep -R <filename> <builddir>)`, but that's a terrible kludge.

**EDIT:** It appears I was mistaken, as I have not been able to duplicate this problem. Manually re-running CMake appears to *always* generate the correct list of `.cpp` files, even using `GLOB` to generate lists of sources.

Comment: Can you please add an example of your `CMakeLists.txt` file(s)? Do you have all your source files listed or do you do a `file(GLOB ...)`? The later is one possibe cause of such kind of bevaviour. See CMake's docu: [We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from your source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to ask CMake to regenerate.](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/file.html)

Comment: @Florian Yes, I do glob files, but I also re-run CMake manually when necessary (and of course whenever I remove the CMake cache).

Comment: Issue [0014820: warn users about removing only CMakeCache.txt](http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=14820) claims you need also to delete all CMakeFiles directories. But I assume you are not caching your list of source files, so from my experience the most reliable way to retrigger the CMake configuration is to touch one of the projects CMakeLists.txt files (e.g. with [CMake itself](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/manual/cmake.1.html#command-line-tool-mode) `cmake -E touch CMakeLists.txt`).

Comment: @Florian most reliable way: why not `cmake <build-dir>` ?

Answer (score 5):

*Turning my comments into an answer*

#### Collecting your source files with `file(GLOB ...)`

Yes, CMake won't know about new or deleted source files when collecting your source files with the `file(GLOB ...)` command. This is a known restriction with CMake. I've changed my CMake project(s) to list all source files individually exactly because of this. Out of convenience I'm still collecting my header files with the `file(GLOB ...)` command.

Quoting from CMake's [`file()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/file.html)  command documentation:

> We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from
>   your source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is
>   added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to
>   ask CMake to regenerate.

#### Deleting `CMakeCache.txt` to retrigger Configuration

Just deleting `CMakeCache.txt` may not be enough to retrigger the CMake configuration. [Issue 0014820: warn users about removing only CMakeCache.txt](http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=14820) claims you need also to delete all `CMakeFiles` directories.

From my experience the most reliable way to retrigger the CMake configuration is to touch one of the projects `CMakeLists.txt` files.

Note: For `ninja` CMake adds a `rebuild_cache` target for conveniently running CMake for your project again.

#### Retrigger after Updates from Source Control

Just one thought: if the deletion of source files happens because they were removed from your source control there maybe a workaround that still allows you to use `file(GLOB ...)` on your source files.

E.g. if you use GIT you could add the following to your main `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
configure_file(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/.git/index ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/git_index.tmp)
```

*Disadvantage*: It would retrigger configuration which each GIT operation (update, commit, ...).

**Some References**:

- [run cmake when adding file in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26972630/run-cmake-when-adding-file-in-eclipse)
- [CMake: Correct way to make an arbitrary file trigger](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2013-October/056062.html)

Comment: This is valuable information, but I did say that I manually re-run CMake when necessary; automatic triggering of reconfiguration isn't really what I'm looking for. The problem is that I seem to be seeing incorrect configuration even when I manually re-run CMake. I need to do some more investigation, though, to double check that I can replicate the issue.

Comment: @KyleStrand Ok, I admit I never had this kind of problem with `ninja` before. I'm using version 1.6 on Windows. So I checked again CMake's Ninja generator and it does completely regenerate `rules.ninja` and `build.ninja` each time you run the configuration again. But the `.ninja_deps` and `.ninja_log` files do survive. I would suggest that - if you want to have a clean `ninja` environment - you add something like `if ("${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" MATCHES "Ninja")` `file(REMOVE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/.ninja_deps")` `endif()` to your main `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: That's a good idea. If I have some spare time I'll play around with this and report back.

Comment: It appears I can't reproduce the issue; re-running CMake does appear to ignore previous source-file entries. I think I may have forgotten to change an `#include` statement last time I had this problem. For now, I'll vote to close.